# python reading and writing from multiple files

Tags: python

```
import os
searchquery = 'word'
with open('C:/Documents/result.txt', 'w') as f:
    for filename in os.listdir('Y:/Documents/data'):
        with open('C:/Documents/data/' + filename) as currentFile:
            text = currentFile.read()
            for line in text:
                if searchquery in line:
                    f.write(searchquery + filename[:-4] + '\n')
                else:
                    print('not here!')
```

Help?! why does this not search multiple files in a directory for "word" and then write the whole line that contains "word" in a new file?

The input files are like this:

```
Blah
Blah
Blah
Blah
Word blah
Blah
```

And I want the output to just write a file that says:

```
Word blah <file name>
Word blah <file name2>
```

Comment: Start by explaining what's the expected result, an example of the input/output and the error(s) you're having (if any).

Comment: The files are huge multi-line text files, each with only one reference to "word" on the 50000th line. There are no errors but it does not seem to find any mentions of "word" within any of the files in the directory. However it definately does open the correct file. The output just contains hundreds of lines of "not here" so it does appear to read and write files but never find the "word". Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

In your code you list `'Y:/Documents/data'`, but your read from `'C:/Documents/data/'`.this is the problem. 
Try this:

```
import os
searchquery = 'word'
with open('C:/Documents/data/result.txt', 'w') as f:
    for filename in os.listdir('Y:/Documents/data/'):
        with open('Y:/Documents/data/' + filename) as currentFile:
            for line in currentFile:
                if searchquery in line:
                    f.write(searchquery + filename + '\n')
                else:
                    print('not here!')
```